# Array item within parentheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array and I need that each item is enclosed within parentheses, but I cant get it done. Here is an example of my code.

```
var pruebaArray = new Array();

$.each(foo, function(i, bar) {                      
    pruebaArray.push(foo[i], bar);
});

console.log(pruebaArray);
```

Output of console.log:

```
["foo", bar, "foo2", bar2]
```

And what I want is:

```
[("foo", bar), ("foo2", bar2)]
```

This would be used like this:

```
RenderPieChart('container', [
    ('foo', bar),
    ('foo2', bar2),
    ('foo3',  bar3),                         
    ('foo4', bar4),
]);
```

Comment: So, you should have a string. right?

Comment: Just 'foo' can be string

Comment: You can't change the data structure.
You won't be able to change { to ( or any other character in the structure

Comment: **[("foo", bar), ("foo2", bar2)]** is not a valid structure. What are you actually trying to accomplish? If you want an array of arrays, you would make it **[["foo", bar], ["foo2", bar2]]**. Beyond that, not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: What do you want those parentheses to mean? A tuple?

Comment: I've update the question

Comment: @jlbriggs _yes_, it is. `[("foo", bar), ("foo2", bar2)]` will be an array with the values of `bar, bar2`, so what you'll get it is an array of `[bar, bar2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with what you're trying to do - first, as you've seen, the `push` method on arrays will allow you to push multiple values in sequence - that is, `[].push(1, 2, 3)` will result in `[1, 2, 3]`

The bigger issue though is that the data that you want doesn't have any meaning within the world of javascript.  You want the first element of the resulting array to be `("foo", bar)`, but that's not a valid object - something like `["foo", bar]` (where you have an array of arrays) would make sense, or `{"foo": bar}`, where you have an array of simple javascript objects would also work.  But `("foo", bar)` isn't valid.

I'd suggest trying either:

```
pruebaArray.push([foo[i], bar]);
```

or

```
pruebaArray.push({foo[i]: bar});
```

Comment: Comma-separated expressions parens to the last item in the expression list, e.g., `("foo", "bar")` evaluates to `"bar"`. It's totally valid, just not what the OP wants.